# Copying a struct's slice parameter in Go

Tags: arrays, go, copy, slice, deep-copy

Let's say I have a struct with a slice parameter like the following, and I create one and fill it with some values:

```
type s struct {
  sl []float32
}

func NewS() *s {
  return &s{
    sl: make([]float32, 3),
  }
}

func main() {
  a := NewS()
  a.sl[0] = 1
  a.sl[1] = 2
  a.sl[2] = 3

  b := NewS()
  // Code here
}
```

I want `b` to have an `sl` with the same values as `a.sl`, and in particular, I'd like to understand how to do it in different ways:

1. Where the entire `b` points to the entire `a` (so that if there were other parameters in the struct, those would all match)
2. Where `b.sl` would point to `a.sl`
3. As a deep copy, where there are no pointers (and done not by iterating through the slice, but by a way that's repeatable regardless of type, ideally)

What follows is what I've tried and found so far.

```
b = a
fmt.Printf("a: %p\n", &a)
fmt.Printf("b: %p\n", &b)
fmt.Printf("a.sl: %p\n", &a.sl)
fmt.Printf("b.sl: %p\n", &b.sl)
```

Which outputs different memory addresses for the structs, but the same memory addresses for the slices. Why is that? Why wouldn't the struct addresses be the same, too, if a is just pointing to b?

```
a: 0xc00000e030
b: 0xc00000e038
a.sl: 0xc000054040
b.sl: 0xc000054040
```

Then I tried:

```
b.sl = a.sl
// ...
```

Which outputs all distinct memory addresses. It makes sense of course that the address of `a` and `b` are different, but why isn't `b.sl` pointing to the address of `a.sl`?

```
a: 0xc00000e028
b: 0xc00000e030
a.sl: 0xc00000c030
b.sl: 0xc00000c048
```

And finally I tried:

```
copy(b.sl, a.sl)
// ...
```

Which outputs similarly to the above. This result is the only one I expected, since I expected this to make a deep copy.

```
a: 0xc0000b8018
b: 0xc0000b8020
a.sl: 0xc0000ae018
b.sl: 0xc0000ae030
```

Could you help me understand what's happening in these 3 cases and other ways to achieve my desire results and perform various types of copies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some background information: A slice contains a pointer to the slice's backing array, the length of the slice and the capacity of the backing array. The (pointer, length, capacity) is referred to as a [slice header](https://godocs.io/reflect#SliceHeader).

The address of a slice is the address of the slice header, not the pointer to the slice's backing array or the first element of the slice's backing array.

**b = a**

The variables `a` and `b` point to the same value after the statement is executed.

The variables a and b are distinct and therefore have different addresses.

The expression `&a.sl` is the address of the `sl` field in the pointed at value. The expression `&b.sl` equals `&a.sl` because `a` and `b` point at the same value.

This is your #1: `a` an `b` point at the same value.

**b.sl = a.sl**

The statement copies the slice header from `a.sl` to `b.sl`. The slices have different addresses because slice headers remain distinct.

This is close to your #2: `a.sl` an `b.sl` point at the same backing array.  A modification to an element in `a.sl` is visible through `b.sl`, but changes to the slice header `a.sl` are not reflected in `b.sl.

**copy(b.sl, a.sl)**

The statement copies the elements in `a.sl`s backing array to `b.sl`.

This is your #3, a deep copy. Changes through `a` are not reflected in `b`.

Answer (score 1):

A slice is a triple containing a pointer to the underlying array, length, and capacity. When you assign a slice to another slice, you assign that triple. The underlying array remains the same.

A slice is a view of an array. If you need a deep copy of a slice, you have to create another slice and copy it yourself.

If you assign an array to another, that copies each element of the source to the target.